# Add codes for dynamically created Active x-check boxes using vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim t As Long
Dim u As Long
Dim v As Long
Dim q As Long
Dim p As Long
t = 1
u = 1    
  Do
    If Sheet2.Range("D" & t).Value = "" Then
      If Sheet2.Range("D" & t + 1).Value = "" Then
        If Sheet2.Range("D" & t + 2).Value = "" Then
          If Sheet2.Range("D" & t + 3).Value = "" Then
            If Sheet2.Range("D" & t + 4).Value = "" Then
              If Sheet2.Range("C" & t).Value = "" Then
                Exit Do
              End If
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
    If Not Sheet2.Range("D" & t).Value = "" Then
      If Not Sheet2.Range("D" & t).Value = "Description" Then
        v = Sheet2.Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "A" & t - 1).Height
        q = Sheet2.Range("A" & t).Height
        p = v + (q / 2) - 5
        Set obj = Sheet2.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.checkbox.1")
        With obj
          .Width = 10
          .Top = p
          .Left = 875
          .Height = 10
        End With
        u = u + 1
      End If
    End If
    t = t + 1
  Loop
```

This Code will help me to create many active-x check boxes as per my requirement as u can see in the image.

check the image,after i click the necessary check boxes,and then the command button "export the nfr", the row corresponding to the selected check box should be copied to another sheet, is there any way to add codes for that manipulation

sorry for editing the question

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF2U2.png

Comment: Use the `and` and the `or` in the `If` statements. Try not to nest them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "custom" check box, by creating an event sunk class, such as this, clsCustomCheckBox

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cb As msforms.CheckBox

Public Sub init(cbInit As msforms.CheckBox)
     Set cb = cbInit
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Click()     ' or the _Change event....
    '   Your code here
End Sub
```

You could then add your new ones, afterwards doing something similar to the below

```
Private c As Collection

Sub testcb()

Dim o As Object
Dim cb As New clsCustomCheckBox

Set o = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1)

cb.init o.Object

Set c = New Collection
c.Add cb

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could switch to a `Form` `Control` instead of an `ActiveX` one and take advantage of its `OnAction` property and assign the same sub to all checkboxes

as follows:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim t As Long, u As Long, v As Long, q As Long, p As Long

    t = 2 '<--| start from 2 otherwise subsequent "A" & (t - 1) would return "A0"!
    u = 1
    With Sheet2
        Do
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells(t, "D").Resize(5), .Cells(t, "C")) < 6 Then Exit Do

            If Not .Cells(t, "D").Value = "Description" Then
                v = .Range("A1", "A" & (t - 1)).Height
                q = .Cells(t, "A").Height
                p = v + (q / 2) - 5
                With .CheckBoxes.Add(875, p, 10, 10) '<--| add a 'Form' checkbox
                    .OnAction = "CheckBoxClick" '<--| current checkbox will "react" calling 'CheckBoxClick()' sub
                End With
                u = u + 1 '<--| what is this for?
            End If
            t = t + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

then you only have to type your `CheckBoxClick()` sub, for instance:

```
Sub CheckBoxClick()
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller) '<--| reference caller checkbox
        MsgBox "hello from " & .Name & " place at cell " & .TopLeftCell.Address
    End With
End Sub
```